# Firefox bug with float and nowrap?

Tags: css

In this fiddle, why is B falling out of the yellow container?

http://jsfiddle.net/en7qfto1/

It does not happen in Chromium.

Is that a Firefox bug?

This is the code:

```
<style>
.a, .b
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightblue;
}

.b
{
    float: right; 
}

.c
{
    background: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div class=c>
    <a class=a>A</a>
    <a class=b>B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh...well it "falls out" as well in Chrome, but I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: @Dan - Not for me it doesn't.

Comment: Oh now I see..I misinterpreted what he meant by "fall out".

Comment: I guess if you remove `white-space: no-wrap` from `c` it fixes the issue. That change doesn't appear to change anything in Chrome

Comment: Yep that did the trick, why is that? post it as an answer

Comment: meh...frankly I don't understand this and why it's happening so I'm not going to post it as an answer.

Comment: Alright so I'll try to explain it as an answer, also pointing to clear floating elements

Comment: @Carlos Calla: Why? It doesn't answer the question in any way. In fact, it completely defeats the question. "Why does X happen when I do Y?" "Because you did Y. So stop doing Y."

Comment: @BoltClock I said I'll explain, not just say. Explain.

Comment: Chromium is the developer build of Chrome, it's available for Windows, Linux, and Mac. It's also installed on Chromebooks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is a bug. You can find the Bugzilla ticket [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725).

David Baron points out the [cause](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725#c8), which indicates in the code itself that this is due to a known limitation:

> The cause is this code in nsLineLayout::ReflowFrame:
>
> ```
>     if (psd->mNoWrap) {
>       // If we place floats after inline content where there's
>       // no break opportunity, we don't know how much additional
>       // width is required for the non-breaking content after the float,
>       // so we can't know whether the float plus that content will fit
>       // on the line. So for now, don't place floats after inline
>       // content where there's no break opportunity. This is incorrect
>       // but hopefully rare. Fixing it will require significant
>       // restructuring of line layout.
>       // We might as well allow zero-width floats to be placed, though.
>       availableWidth = 0;
>     }
> ```
>
> I wonder whether the right thing to do is:
>
> - not manipulate the available width at all, or
> - make the available width infinite, since the nowrap content is never going to wrap around the float anyway
>
> (In theory, the correct solution is not to try placing the float until the following break opportunity.  I wonder if other browsers do that.)
>
> I actually think this is quite doable; we already defer layout of floats in mBelowCurrentLineFloats; we just need to do something similar and notify line layout at break opportunities.  It's far from trivial, though.  (We also need to place the float immediately if we're currently at a break opportunity... I think.)

I too wonder if that is what other browsers do (Chrome and IE behave the same, placing the float on the same line as the inline-block). Unfortunately I don't fully understand the interaction between floats and [line breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model), so I can't comment further.

Comment: I was going to post it haha, yes it was a bug.

Comment: It feels pretty bad when I have to put in workarounds for a bug that was reported more than 9 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same bug, and for me the best workaround was to use an equivalent flexbox layout: http://jsfiddle.net/nquyefaq/.

It behaves the same on Chrome, Firefox and IE11:

- Both items render on the same line, with `inline-block` type behaviour.
- The second item is right-aligned. (Instead of `float: right` it uses `margin-left: auto`.)
- If the items have fixed width (mine do), the second item drops down onto the next line if the container becomes too narrow.

I hope this helps someone else looking for a workaround.